# Retrieve specific field from an object of Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, json, generics, dynamic-cast

I need someone's help to retrieve the fields from a Map.

Here is my code :

```
Private List<Job> allJobs;
public void getAllIds(Event e) {

   Map<String, Object> rs=null;

   for(Job j:allJobs) {

       // Contains key as 'data' and value as object (might be any class)
       rs=j.getVariable(id);

       // Here I need get the company id from the object of 'rs'
   }
}
```

Here is one of my class structure which is passing to `Object`:

```
class Server {
      UserContext userContext;
}

class UserContext {
      int companyId;
}
```

I need to get this company id from `rs` above.

How can I achieve this *without* casting the object to the class type?

Or can I cast this object type to dynamic class type if we know the class name (as `String`)?

Comment: You are extending **UserContext** as well as you have it as a property of **Server**??

Comment: you need to elaborate your question. is j.getVariable(id); returning a Map<String, Object> ? Also, what is companyId here? Does the map have the UserContext as the object (value of the key value pair in the map)

Comment: Hrishikesh, Thanks for reply. Ya j.getVariable(id); returning a Map<String, Object>. In this case object is type of 'Server' class. And server class has UserContext property which has companyId property.

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to use Object? You can add an interface like this:

```
interface Accessible<T> {
    T getValue();
}
```

And then use it like this for those classes, which can be stored in *rs*:

```
class Server implements Accessible<Integer> {
    UserContext userContext;

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return userContext.getCompanyId();
    }
}
```

And in your method:

```
private List<Job> allJobs;
public void getAllIds(Event e) {
    Map<String, Accessible<Integer>> rs=null;

    for(Job j:allJobs) {
        rs=j.getVariable(id);
        int myCompanyId = rs.get("my_company").getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, but here j.getVariable(id); returing map<String, Object> type ie here Object type not only Server class, it can be any class type(i mean dynamic conversion to the class to object type).

Comment: Can you make j.getVariable(id) return Map<String, Accessible>?

Comment: No, I don't think so as I have different classes

Comment: Let`s take a look. You have different classes, which have different goals. But you want to handle them in a similar way, while getting some info from them. So that`s why I suggest you to use an interface, which should be implemented by all of your classes, which can be received from j.getVariable(id). In other words it will mean "this classes are different, but all of them can be Accessible to obtain some value using a class-specific logic".

Comment: Here I have different classes like Server class and if I write the same getValue function in every class by implementing Accessible<Integer> interface, then while calling it from getAllJobs(Event e), how can it differentiate it from class to class ?

Comment: Here i don't know which class type is coming from object 'j'. so dynamically I want to cast it to the specified class. here I can get the class name as string from object 'j'.

Comment: Why do you need to know the class of 'j' object? Is it possible to move the logic somewhere inside the object itself so Accessible.getValue() will give you what you need from 'j'?

Comment: If you came to "List<Job> allJobs", then it makes sense to use "Job" class as something abstract. I would try to avoid casting to a concrete class.